# Webpack DLL ignored

Tags: webpack, dll, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I've been trying to set up the DllPlugin on a webpack4 configuration, but whatever I try, the dll is just ignored and the bundles contain all vendor code in them as well.

The vendor-manifest.json is generated, however it does nothing in the main webpack configuration.

Here are the config files:

```js
// webpack.vendor.config.js
'use strict';
var webpack = require('webpack')
var MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require('path');
const libs = [
    "@peopleweek/react-org-chart",
    "classnames",
    "currency-formatter",
    "draft-js",
    "draftjs-to-html",
    "font-awesome-filetypes",
    "get-value",
    "has-value",
    "history",
    "html-to-draftjs",
    "i18n-iso-countries",
    "immutable",
    "interactjs",
    "json-form-data",
    "jsondiffpatch",
    "lodash",
    "memoize-one",
    "moment",
    "moment-timezone",
    "normalizr",
    "object-hash",
    "object.assign",
    "promise-polyfill",
    "prop-types",
    "query-string",
    "react",
    "react-autosuggest",
    "react-avatar-editor",
    "react-beautiful-dnd",
    "react-big-calendar",
    "react-bootstrap",
    "react-calendar-timeline",
    "react-color",
    "react-d3",
    "react-dates",
    "react-datetime",
    "react-dom",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg",
    "react-dropzone",
    "react-geosuggest",
    "react-google-recaptcha",
    "react-infinite-scroller",
    "react-linkify",
    "react-moment",
    "react-moment-proptypes",
    "react-number-format",
    "react-redux",
    "react-resize-to-aspect-ratio",
    "react-responsive",
    "react-responsive-tabs",
    "react-router-dom",
    "react-select",
    "react-share",
    "react-tether",
    "react-toastify",
    "react-url-query",
    "react-visjs-timeline",
    "recharts",
    "redux",
    "redux-socket.io",
    "redux-thunk",
    "set-value",
    "socket.io-client",
    "sugarss",
    "tz-ids",
    "vis",
    "whatwg-fetch",
];
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        vendor: libs
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'vendor_lib'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: ['fr', 'it', 'de', 'es', 'pt'],
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        }),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            name: 'vendor_lib',
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            /**
             * Compiles ES6 and ES7 into ES5 code
             * Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
             */
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/i,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {}
            },
            /**
             * Compile SASS to CSS, then use same rules
             * Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader
             */
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                enforce: 'pre'
            },

            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractFilePlugin = require('extract-file-loader/Plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig(options) {
    /**
     * Whether we are running in dev-server mode (versus simple compile)
     */
    var DEV_SERVER = process.env.WEBPACK_MODE === 'watch';

    var mode = DEV_SERVER ? 'development' : 'production';

    var tenant = options.parameters.APP_ENV.indexOf('tenant_') === 0 ? options.parameters.APP_ENV.substr(7) : null;

    /**
     * Whether we are running inside webpack-dashboard
     */
    var DASHBOARD = process.env.WEBPACK_DASHBOARD === 'enabled';

    var publicPath;
    if (options.parameters.dev_server_public_path && DEV_SERVER) {
        publicPath = options.parameters.dev_server_public_path;

    } else if (options.parameters.public_path) {
        publicPath = options.parameters.public_path;
    } else {
        publicPath = DEV_SERVER ? '//localhost:8080/compiled/' : '/compiled/';
    }


    var tenantStylesVariablesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/Resources/assets/tenant/styles/_variables.scss');

    if (tenant) {
        var temp = tenant ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/config/tenants',  tenant ,'/styles/_variables.scss') : null;
        if (fs.existsSync(temp)) {
            tenantStylesVariablesPath = temp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {
        entry: options.entry,
        mode: mode,
        resolve: {
            alias: Object.assign({}, options.alias, {
                '@tenant-styles-variables': tenantStylesVariablesPath
            }),
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        },
        optimization: Object.assign({
            minimize: false,
            // splitChunks: {
            //     cacheGroups: {
            //         commons: {
            //             test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            //             name: 'vendors',
            //             chunks: 'all'
            //         }
            //     }
            // }
        }, DEV_SERVER ? {
            removeAvailableModules: false,
            removeEmptyChunks: false,
        }: {}),
        output: Object.assign({
            // Absolute output directory
            path: options.parameters.path ? options.parameters.path : path.resolve(__dirname, '/web/compiled/'),

            // Output path from the view of the page
            publicPath: publicPath,

            // Filename for entry points
            // Only adds hash in build mode
            filename: DEV_SERVER ? '[name].bundle.js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',

            // Filename for non-entry points
            // Only adds hash in build mode
            chunkFilename: DEV_SERVER ? '[name].bundle.js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        }, DEV_SERVER ? {
            // dev serveer only options
            pathinfo: false
        } : {}),

        /**
         * Options for webpack-dev-server.
         * Enables overlay inside the page if any error occurs when compiling.
         * Enables CORS headers to allow hot reload from other domain / port.
         * Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
         */
        devServer: Object.assign({
            overlay: {
                warnings: false,
                errors: true
            },
            disableHostCheck: true,
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
        }, options.parameters.dev_server || {})
    };


    /**
     * Loaders
     * Reference: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/
     * List: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
     * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
     */
    config.module = {
        rules: [
            /**
             * Compiles ES6 and ES7 into ES5 code
             * Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
             */
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/i,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {}
            },
            /**
             * Copy files to output directory
             * Rename the file using the asset hash
             * Pass along the updated reference to your code
             *
             * Reference: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader
             *
             * Query string is needed for URLs inside css files, like bootstrap
             * Overwrites name parameter to put original name in the destination filename, too
             */
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?.*)?$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash].[ext]'
                }
            },

            /**
             * Loads HTML files as strings inside JavaScript - can be used for templates
             *
             * Reference: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
             */
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },

            /**
             * Compile SASS to CSS, then use same rules
             * Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader
             */
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                loader: ['sass-loader'],
                enforce: 'pre'
            },

            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: DEV_SERVER ? [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                ] : [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                ],
            }
        ]
    };

    if (!DEV_SERVER) {
        config.module.rules.push(
            /**
             * Minify PNG, JPEG, GIF and SVG images with imagemin
             * Reference: https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader
             *
             * See `config.imageWebpackLoader` for configuration options
             *
             * Query string is needed for URLs inside css files, like bootstrap
             */
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)(\?.*)?$/i,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                options: options.parameters.image_loader_options || {
                    optipng: {
                        optimizationLevel: 7,
                        progressive: true
                    }
                }
            }
        )

    }

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
     * List: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/
     */
    config.plugins = [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            // context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
            // manifest: path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
        // // To strip all locales except the ones supported
        // // (“en” is built into Moment and can’t be removed)
        // new MomentLocalesPlugin({
        //     localesToKeep: ['fr', 'it', 'de', 'es', 'pt'],
        // }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: DEV_SERVER ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: DEV_SERVER ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
        }),

        /**
         * Webpack plugin that emits a json file with assets paths - used by the bundle
         * Reference: https://github.com/kossnocorp/assets-webpack-plugin
         */
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: path.basename(options.manifest_path),
            path: path.dirname(options.manifest_path)
        }),

        /**
         * Adds assets loaded with extract-file-loader as chunk fies to be available in generated manifest
         * Used by the bundle to use binary files (like images) as entry-points
         * Reference: https://github.com/mariusbalcytis/extract-file-loader
         */
        new ExtractFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: DEV_SERVER ? 'development' : 'production',
            DEBUG: DEV_SERVER
        })
    ];

    /**
     * Adds CLI dashboard when compiling assets instead of the standard output
     * Reference: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/webpack-dashboard
     */
    if (DASHBOARD) {
        config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
    }

    /**
     * Devtool - type of sourcemap to use per build type
     * Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
     */
    if (DEV_SERVER) {
        config.devtool = 'eval';
    } else {
        config.devtool = 'none';
    }

    console.log(config.plugins[0]);
    return config;
};
```

I tried finding answers, but all example configurations look exactly like ours. Obviously the main config here is more complicated then most examples, but the main parts are pretty much 1:1 to all examples I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution. For some reason although I couldn't find it in the documentation, I have to specify the name.

```js
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
     context: __dirname,
     manifest: require('./dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
     name: 'vendor_lib'
})
```